# gnuplot: set palette labels with smallest numbers on top

Tags: gnuplot, label, color-palette

I am making palette in gnuplot using commands:

```
set pm3d implicit at b
set palette model RGB maxcolors 5
set cbrange [0:20]
set palette model RGB defined (4 '#006400', 8 '#00008B', 12 'blue', 16 '#C71585', 20 'red')
set cbtics 4
```

This way I get order 20,16,12,8,4,0 from top to bottom on my vertical palette.
I need 0,4,8,12,16,20 reading from top to bottom.

I did not find any example already existing with this order (from smallest to biggest).

Thank you for your suggestions:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hm, there seems not to be an easy way to to this. One solution would be to redefine the colorbar-tics

```
set cbtics ("20" 0,"16" 4,"12" 8,"8" 12,"4" 16,"0" 20)
```

and now you splot 20 minus the normal data. Then the colors should be again correct.

Comment: You are right, just yesterday my friend finally adviced me this:set pm3d implicit at b
set palette model RGB defined (4 '#006400', 8 '#00008B', 12 'blue', 16 '#C71585', 20 'red')
set cbrange [80:100]
set cbtics 4 ("0" 100, "4" 96, "8" 92, "12" 88, "16" 84, "20" 80)